# Double For Each Loops

Tags: vb.net

What is wrong with this loop ?

I've noticed that the `a` string doesn't change but I guess it's supposed to move to the next string in list, whereas it works fine for `ProxyList`.

```
Public Class Form1

    Public ProxyList As New List(Of String)
    Public AccountList As New List(Of String)

    For Each a As String In AccountList
        Dim z() As String = a.Split(":")

        For Each p As String In ProxyList
           ' SENDS WEBREQUESTS BY USING ACCOUNTS AND SETS PROXY '
        Next
    Next
```

End Class

Comment: How many strings do you have in `AccountList`?

Comment: over 150+ but it just doesnt skip the first one .

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  Are any exceptions being thrown?  It might help if you show the code where you initialize `AccountList`.

Comment: Where is `item` defined?   You're splitting on it - don't you want to split on `a`?

Comment: i have initialised both the lists below "Public Class Form1" and above all the subs .

Comment: You have a nested for each loop there. Are you looking for something like AccountList and ProxyList should keep moving forward to next item every iteration? Currently, after the items are over in the ProxyList, next value from AccountList would be fetched.

Comment: @Prash thats is what im looking for .

Comment: @Tim it was a misatake while posting code here i change the variable name but forgot to change to make change right there so i corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through Account list once for every item in proxyList, if there are 5 items in account list and 10 in proxyList then this code will loop 50 times. There is nothing wrong with this code except it doesn't match what you wanted.

From your comment you want accountList and proxyList to both advance forward equally, you should really define a new class:

```
Public Class ProxyAccount
    Public Proxy As String
    Public Account As String
End Class
```

Then your code becomes:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public ProxyList As New List(Of ProxyAccount)

    For Each pa As ProxyAccount In ProxyList 
        Dim a as String = pa.Account
        Dim z() As String = a.Split(":") 
        Dim p as String = pa.Proxy   
        ' SENDS WEBREQUESTS BY USING ACCOUNTS AND SETS PROXY '
        Next
    Next
End Class
```

Or you can do this as well:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public ProxyList As New List(Of String)
    Public AccountList As New List(Of String)

    For i as Integer = 0 To ProxyList.Count - 1  
        If i >= AccountList.Count Then   
            Exit For
        End If
        Dim a As String = AccountList(i)    
        Dim z() As String = a.Split(":")  
        Dim p as String = ProxyList(i)  
        ' SENDS WEBREQUESTS BY USING ACCOUNTS AND SETS PROXY '
    Next
End Class
```

Either of these two work just fine, but you will want to refactor the code to be cleaner.

Comment: thanks for helping me out, I tried the second one and it worked :D